# Logout funcionality via local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, local-storage

So here I have Login funcionality via local storage token. I am getting the token upon user being created in The dev tools/Application  it is redirecting me to the home that is working. The thing that is not working is this. Creating an user it is working but when it loads it should show logout instead of login, and should hide the cart Component. Where am I making a mistake
Context Api

```
import React from "react";
const UserContext = React.createContext();

function getUserFromLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("authToken")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authToken"))
      : { username: null, token: null };
  }

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(getUserFromLocalStorage());
  
    const history = useHistory();
    const logoutHandler = () =>{
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      history.push("/")
  }
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{ user, logoutHandler  }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { UserContext, UserProvider };
```

Login Link

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "../../context/user";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
export default function LoginLink() {

  const { user, logoutHandler } = React.useContext(UserContext);

  if (user.authToken) {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          logoutHandler();
        }}
        className="login-btn"
      >
        logout
      </button>
    );
  }
  return <Link to="/login">login</Link>;
}
```

Header

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Search from './Search';
import './Header.css'
import SearchBooks from './SearchBooks';
import LoginLink from '../Signin/LoginLink';
import CartLink from '../Cart/CartLink';
import { UserContext } from '../../context/user';

const Header = () => {
const { user } = React.useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <div className='header__container'>
            <Link to='/'>
            <img src='/audi.png' />
            </Link>  
            <li>
              <LoginLink />
            </li>
           {user.authToken &&(
            <CartLink /> 
           )    
           }      
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Login Component

```
import { useState, } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Signin.css";

const Login = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory()

  
  const loginHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const config = {
      header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login",
        { email, password },
        config
      );

      localStorage.setItem("authToken", data.token);
      setUser(user)
      history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        setError(error.response.data.error);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
         setError("");
      }, 5000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-screen">
      <form onSubmit={loginHandler} className="login-screen__form">
        <h3 className="login-screen__title">Login</h3>
        {error && <span className="error-message">{error}</span>}
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            required
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            value={email}
            tabIndex={1}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">
            Password:{" "}
            <Link to="/forgotpassword" className="login-screen__forgotpassword">
              Forgot Password?
            </Link>
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            required
            id="password"
            autoComplete="true"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            value={password}
            tabIndex={2}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Login
        </button>

        <span className="login-screen__subtext">
          Don't have an account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
        </span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you login, you have only set the authToken into your localStorage and not in your Provider. You'll need to call setUser after you login in order for Header component to know user is logged in.

Comment: I have updated the code in the Login Component, could that work